# Engineering OOP model where you register handlers for class types

Tags: java, oop

I've created a `Settings` class that automatically retrieves or prints setting value on associated `JTextField`. My binding function looks like this:

```
public void bindToInput(final String setting_name, final JTextField input, final SettingsInputVerifier<Object> verif);
```

However, I want to use more types of `JComponent`. I've already created more abstract input representation - interface `Input`:

```
public interface Input {
  /** Retrieve the field associated with this abstract input.
   * @return JComponent field. Use `instanceof` to check for type.
   */
  public JComponent getField();
  /**
   * Will put the best possible representation of the value in the input.
   * @param value to appear in the input
   */
  public void setValue(Object value);
  /** Parse input field value and turn it into object.
   * @return Object representing parsed value of the input field
   */
  public Object getValue();
  /**
   * Check if the value in JComponent is valid using the associated verifier.
   * @return true if the value is valid and can be turned into type <T>
   */
  public boolean validate();
  /**
   * Retrieve the internal verifier.
   * @return SettingsInputVerifier
   */
  public SettingsInputVerifier<Object> getVerifier();
  /**
   * Change the internal verifier.
   * @param ver verifier to replace the original input verifier. Pass null to skip value verification.
   */
  public void setVerifier(SettingsInputVerifier<Object> ver);
  /**
   * Add the verifier
   */
  public void bind();
  /**
   * Remove the verifier from input, do not call onchange event any more
   */
  public void unbind();
}
```

It now seems that I'd have to use long `else if` chains to use the proper `Input` implementation for given `JComponent`. Like this:

```
//InputJTextField, InpuJToggleButton are, WLOG, some classes inplementing Input
public static Input fromJComponent(JComponent something) {
     if(something instanceof JTextField)
       return new InputJTextField(something);
     else if(something instanceof JToggleButton)
       return new InpuJToggleButton(something);
     if(... and so on...
        ...
     else
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("This input type is not supported.");
}
```

Instead of this `else if` chain, I'd like to have an option to register somewhere every class implementing `Input`:

```
class InputJToggleButton implements Input {
    //Register the association with this class and the input type it represents
    private final boolean registered = Input.register(InputJToggleButton, JToggleButton);
}
```

Then the `fromJComponent` method would look up some `HashMap<Type, Type>` and find whether there's a valid implementation for given `JComponent`.

Is this flexibility possible? Or will I have to manually add every implementation in the `else if` chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can register a map from a component class to an input class:

```
Map<Class<? extends JComponent>, Class<? extends Input>> inputRegistry;
```

The register() call will look something like this:

```
Input.register(JToggleButton.class, InputJToggleButton.class);
```

Then you can get the Input class from a Map:

```
inputRegistry.get(component.getClass());
```

and then use reflection(`Class.newInstance()`) to create an Input instance.

Comment: I guess the only trick to call `register` implicitly is to assign it's return value to static property, is it?

Comment: The register() method doesn't need to return anything. The inputRegistry map should be a static field.

Comment: But how do you call it if it doesn't return anything? I mean, you can't call methods in `class` body unless you're assigning static property.

Comment: Why do you need to call it in `class` body? You can have a method anywhere in your program that will register all the mappings by calling the `register` method for all the classes.

Comment: And actually you can call any methods from an initializer block of a class. `class InputJToggleButton { static { Input.register(...) } }`